# Text color with fading over time effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Is there any way i can do fading/decay color effect on html text by javascript or css?

right now i read from database and append the text to a div, the text initially would be blue color and it will decay to black color over certain amount of time (like 5 secs).

right now i just appending text to `div` with

`$('#txtBox1').append("#"+ data.message[i]+ "</br>");`

Comment: You would need to use jQuery UI to animate color, or you can use some jQuery color plugin.

Comment: Google `CSS animations`

Comment: Just set the initial class that has `transition: all 5 ease`, then set it to another class using jQuery that has a black color.

Comment: @remyabel You're right but it's more easily done with CSS animations

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Can be easily done with CSS animations.

Here's an example.

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/7DT7v/3/)

```
.fading {
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-animation-name: fading;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-name: fading;
}
@-webkit-keyframes fading {
    from {
        color: blue;
    }
    to {
        color: black;
    }
}
@keyframes fading {
    from {
        color: blue;
    }
    to {
        color: black;
    }
}
```

Comment: but its not changing from blue to black, its always black in the demo

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: i am using chrome, just tried it on IE and it worked, anyway to make it work with chrome?

Comment: @3v01 Fixed. I forgot to set keyframes for `-webkit` browsers

Comment: Once the animation is complete the colour returns to the default (black). This is fine for the question but if like me you're fading _from_ black to another colour, you can fix this by adding `color: blue` to the `.fading` class

Answer (score 1):

Most browser already [support CSS transitions](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-transitions):

```
#txtBox1 {
    color:blue;
    -webkit-transition:color 5s;
    transition:color 5s;
}
#txtBox1.black {
    color:black;
}
```

To start the color effect, you need to add the className `black`

```
$('#txtBox1').addClass('black');
```

<kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RienNeVaPlus/QexYk/1/)**</kbd>

Comment: Although if he's appending elements, it may desirable to do this on the appended elements, rather than on the containing element.

Comment: I tried to post my current progress with your code, but its too hard to read as comments, please help me to check in the post on the bottom, thx

Answer (score 0):

On modern browsers, you can use CSS3 transitions, as shown by @RienNeVaPlus

On older browsers, you can add [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) to your project to add animation support for CSS colours.  It's possible to obtain a [custom jQuery UI build](http://jqueryui.com/download/) that only contains the essential features without all the rest of the widgets.

Answer (score 0):

(couldnt format code in comment, so posting reply)
i tried to modify RienNeVaPlus's code to the following:

```
$.ajax({...
    success: function(data) {
           for (var i = 0; i < data.message.length; i++) { 
                   txt = "<p id='line"+count+i+"' class='fadingColor'># "+ data.message[i]+ "</p>"
                   $('#txtBox1').append(txt);
                   $('#line'+count+i).addClass('black');
            }
             count = data.count;}
```

css

```
.fadingColor {
    color:blue;
    -webkit-transition:color 5s;
    transition:color 5s;
 }
.fadingColor.black {
    color:black;
}
```

but it always shows black color, from chrome inspect element:

```
<p id="line050" class="fadingColor black"># Zone 3 Opened</p>
```